# Identifying File Type of a File without extension

Tags: filesystems, encryption, hex-editor

I have a quite a large file (>50gb) that has no file extension and is possibly encrypted. I created this file a while ago, but I accidentally removed the extension but I think it is possibly a compressed file (e.g. .7z, .rar). I know the password if I am able to identify which application can open it.

How is it possible to identify which file type this file belongs to (bearing in mind it might be encrypted - but I know the encrypted password if there is one)?

I tried using a Hex Editor but weird characters are shown most likely because it is encrypted.

**Further Information:** 
Hopefully this should be helpful:

- I would have created this file on a Windows operating system
- The hex editor has text 0x0 to 0x200 followed by a massive whitespace before contents/text resumes at 0x20000.

Comment: A compression utility such as 7zip should be able to identify the file even without an extension. Just try opening it with this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "encrypted" you mean that you used a password during the compression process to encrypt the file, 7Zip can handle this without issue.

If you have the 7zip shell extension, just right-click on the file and select the 7zip option to extract. It'll identify the file itself and present a password prompt to you for decryption.

I tested this just now by creating a 3GB archive from an ISO with a password (and encrypted file names), removed the extension, and asked 7zip to open it.

Comment: Yes by encrypted I mean password protected. 7-zip (Ez7z) gives me the following error: "Can’t make last item of {} into type string. (-1700)". I think on Windows it says not valid archive.

Comment: Then it sounds as though you can probably add corrupted to the list of characteristics of this archive.

Comment: +1 - You are probably right - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

did you try on *nix ?:
`#file your_filename`
where "file" - is a program usually lives here /usr/bin/file
you can install it using package manager, or get it there ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/

Comment: I have tried on mac - it just says `filename: data` where `filename` is the name of file.